# What is the difference between firebase web and firebease android?

Tags: firebase

Since I am making a mobile application using Firebase WEB and it has all the features of real time database and storage

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDKs for the web platform allow you to build applications that run a browser (Chrome, Firefox, etc), or in another supported environment that runs JavaScript. If you're building a web application, these are all you'll have to deal with.

The Firebase SDKs for Android allow you to build applications that run directly on Android, instead of inside a browser. These are usually written in Java or Kotlin, instead of in JavaScript.

Many Firebase products are available on all three primary platforms that Firebase supports (iOS, Android, and Web). Some growth products (such as Dynamic Links, In-App Messaging, and App Distribution) are only available on iOS and Android though.

Comment: i'm using firebase web in reactnative, would that be a problem?

Comment: If you want to use Firebase in your React Native app, have a look here: https://rnfirebase.io/ If you're having problems, please be specific about the problem.